# How to execute a cron job (e.g., using hangfire) every two weeks on Sunday starting from a given date?

Tags: c#, cron, hangfire

I would like to know how I can set up [hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/)'s cron expression to schedule a job that runs every two weeks on Sunday starting from today. I tried to use a [cron expression generator](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) but I still cannot see how to solve this.

Comment: Hi, here is the file with example cron schedule https://github.com/tahmedb/reportSchedule/blob/main/Startup.cs
you can replace Cron.Hourly line with cron generator cron

Comment: @ToufiqAhmed I am not sure if I misunderstood you but the problem I have is not how to use the cron schedule. Rather, the problem I have is how to create a cron that execute every 2 weeks

Comment: check this out https://crontab.guru/#30_00_1-7,15-20,29-31_*_0 you can tweak it a little
https://sharadchhetri.com/run-cron-job-alternate-week-day/